# how to get distinct month name from listdate in angularjs(Pending)

Tags: angularjs, angular

hi all i am using angularjs i have a set of listed data  called date's .now i have 12 checkbox with month name like january february March ......when i select january i need to get january data's based on below data may be user can select multi month also  i need to show the year based checkbox Month selection in ng-repeat help how to do this  Month/date/year(4/1/2016)

## Data

```
7/1/2016
8/1/2016
9/1/2016
10/1/2016
11/1/2016
2/1/2017
3/1/2017
5/1/2016
6/1/2016
7/1/2016
8/1/2016
9/1/2016
10/1/2016
11/1/2016
```

Comment: Show us your code, we're not interested in a huge list of random dates

Comment: wait i will update my question